# arraylist returning random numbers and not proper data

Tags: java

so I've got an arraylist

```
private static ArrayList<Job> teamNoOne = new ArrayList<Job>();
```

Of type Job, which has

```
public class Job {
    //public long time;
    public int teamNo;
    public String regNo;
    public String gridRef;

}
```

Then I'm getting data from a textField

```
Job job = new Job();
job.gridRef = tfGridRef.getText();
```

This all works, printed it to system etc.

When I add it to the arraylist, and print it out using the following code:

```
teamNoOne.add(job);

System.out.println(teamNoOne.get(0));
```

I just get this: `Job@1c79dfc`

cannot for the life of me figure out why,

Cheers

Comment: Try System.out.println(teamNoOne.get(0).getText());

You're seeing the object identifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a object is printed using sysout, its `toString` method is called. If `toString` method is not overridden in the class, then its default implementation will be used. Default implementation of an object `toString` method prints the class name and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object separated by `@` symbol.

You need to override the `toString` method in your `Job` class in order to print the object in a pretty way. Most of the IDEs provide a way to auto- generate the `toString` method. Here is one generated through eclipse:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Job [teamNo=" + teamNo + ", regNo=" + regNo + ", gridRef="
            + gridRef + "]";
}
```

Comment: @user2761143 Yes add it to the Job class and see the magic ;-)

Comment: @user2761143 No probs , just accept the answer if it helped. Accepting an answer helps other facing the same problem.

Comment: yeah of course! it said I had to wait because I don't have much rep :)

have a good day